# Update position of an object by Sensors / Orientation manager

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, sensormanager

I wanted to know if there a way to get Glass current orientation/position in degrees or something.
and by getting that, I want to be able to move an object (could be an image, and I will rotate it )

Thanks.

Comment: See this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Alex K, go through a tutorial about sensors, or look at the official document [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html).

Additionally, consider `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY`.

Regarding moving your object, refer to `rotate()` on [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).